# Avoid running compinit at each zsh startup

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion, clap

I build a huge zsh completion file for my program using [`clap_complete`](https://docs.rs/clap_complete/latest/clap_complete/). To activate it, I added in my `~/.zshrc` the lines:

```
fpath+=(~/.zsh/completion) # adding my completion directory to the fpath
compinit # running completion
```

However, the `compinit` line doubles the load time of each new terminal (opened with `Ctrl+Shift+T` for instance).

Is there a way to somehow cache the `compinit` call so it's only run once?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you open the terminal, it starts the whole process over again. So even if you tried to cache compinit, and then opened a new one, then it would skip component and you wouldn't have your autocomplete setup.